# If/else statements not displaying correctly to console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the console to read "No goal!" but every time I run it, I get "Goal". I'm guessing there's some basic syntax error that I'm making?

```
let isSoccerFan = false;
if (isSoccerFan=true) {
console.log("Goal!");
} else{
console.log("No goal!")
}
```

Comment: `=` means assignment. `==` or `===` means comparison

Comment: it should be either  `isSoccerFan === true` or simply `isSoccerFan`

Comment: No research effort (if you researched you would have known what is `=`)

Comment: Try to use `==` or `===`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not correct. Try this:

```js
let isSoccerFan = false;
if (isSoccerFan) {
  console.log('Goal!');
} else {
  console.log('No goal!');
}
```

Comment: Please explain what went wrong though it is obvious